# Woocommerce hooks not fires

Tags: php, woocommerce, plugins, hook, hook-woocommerce

i'm new on Wordpress because i come to .net/asp.net world.
I'm realizing a plugin, that add some hooks to customize cart's expirience.
When i add this hook for the exemple:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'test_before_cart');

function test_before_cart(){
  print_r('test');
}
```

seem that function doesn't called, and not print the message.
In my child theme file function.php, i added this

```
function add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_woocommerce_support' );
```

but it still doesn't work.

Anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: If you use woo blocks then you cant use these hooks. If you use php cart template and doesnt work maybe check if HPOS is enabled. Here is good article by woo devs for blocks - https://developer.woo.com/2023/08/07/extending-the-woocommerce-checkout-block-to-add-custom-shipping-options/

Comment: Thanks! I removed the default style in cart page about Storefront and put it shortcode [woocommerce_cart]. Now work!